# Make each run of python interpreter automatically call `coverage`?

Tags: python, coverage.py

I have test.sh that runs `python` command on many different scripts. Is there a way to emit `coverage -a` for each python call without prepending each command with `coverage -a`?

Comment: What OS are you on? You could alias the command on Linux.

Comment: @PeterWood Linux, but something tells me that aliasing won't really work well - note that `coverage run nosetests` doesn't work.

Comment: "coverage run nosetests" doesn't work because "python nosetests" doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the coverage.py docs about subprocess measurement for a way to invoke coverage automatically when starting Python: http://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/latest/subprocess.html .  It will require some fiddling.

It might be easier to alias in the shell script.  For things like "nosetests", change it to "python -m nose".